# How to know the time of compilation

Tags: malware, forensics, c, c++

I've read that a malware found by kaspersky was compiled at the moscow time zone. How they know the time of compilation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get the compilation/linking date/time, for instance from the [COFFHeader.TimeDateStamp](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files#COFF_Header) field. But that doesn't give you the time zone as the field is just ["the number of seconds elapsed since midnight (00:00:00), January 1, 1970, UTC"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680313(v=vs.85).aspx). I presume Kaspersky concluded a Moscow TZ by looking at the compile date/time of multiple different versions and seeing most are between 4AM UTC (8AM Moscow) and 2PM UTC (6PM Moscow) (similar to an analysis FireEye did in their [Apt28 report, page 27](https://www2.fireeye.com/rs/fireye/images/rpt-apt28.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is possible to detect the compilation date/time/timezone until and unless the malware has specified it inside explicitly.

The time reported by Kaspersky must be the date/time/timezone when the first threat of such malware was reported to the Kaspersky virus database.